# ZF2 - Register/Login overlay in it's own action, JS to open and possible to deep link

Tags: zend-framework2

I have overlays and a hidden panel on my site which uses AJAX to pull in content from another controller/action. You click a link which pushState the URL and AJAX pulls in the content with `setTerminal(true);` so there is no layout wrapped around. These overlay/hiddenpanels are login/register and would also like them to already be in HTML when you request the page without ajax (refresh) so they can be deeplinked to.

Currently I have something like this in the register controller/action:

```
public function registerAction () {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // Possible $form = new RegisterForm(); with validation and error population etc

    // If we're not requesting via AJAX, forward dispatch to index
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->forward()->dispatch('index', array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'overlay' => 1
        ));
    }

    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;

}
```

If there isn't an XmlHttpRequest then it forward dispatches to index/index with the following check:

```
public function indexAction () {
    $routeRequest = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();

    $view = new ViewModel([]);

    // Check if user went to somewhere like register page
    $overlay = $routeRequest->getParam('overlay', null);
    if (null !== $overlay) {
        $view->overlay = true;
    }

    return $view;
}
```

In my layout I'm checking if the view has the overlay view variable set and then including the overlay in HTML for the previous action like so (controllerName and actionName ViewHelpers get populated onBootstrap so contain `register` as controller etc):

```
// Layout.phtml
if ($viewVariables->overlay) {
    echo $this->partial('application/' . $this->controllerName() . '/' . $this->actionName() . '.phtml');
}
```

But this currently doesn't contain any data from the registerAction. I was thinking of having a registration form and having everything registration related done inside there as well and having it accessible where-ever I might forward dispatch to but now it's getting rather complex forwarding and passing variables about.

I was thinking of creating a ViewHelper like `echo $this->overlay()` which would contain ViewVariables from the previous view and include the other view as a partial but then also thought about passing the view from registerAction to indexAction via the forward dispatcher and nesting it.

Right now i'm triggering statechange with JS at the bottom of the page which takes the current URL and grabs it via AJAX but making the user wait for a full page render and then loading symbol after that is confusing when it can already be there.

This seems a rather complex problem as I'm not too familiar with what's available. I'm seeing alot of modules with the eventManager so am wondering how others would approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this and it was easier than I expected.

```
// RegisterController/indexAction
public function registerAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $view = new ViewModel();

    // If we're not requesting via AJAX, forward dispatch to index
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $view->setTemplate('application/register/index');
        return $this->forward()->dispatch('index', array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'overlay' => $view
        ));
    }

    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;
}

// IndexController/indexAction
public function indexAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $routeRequest = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();

    $view = new ViewModel();

    $overlay = $routeRequest->getParam('overlay', null);
    if (null !== $overlay) {
        $view->addChild($overlay, 'overlay');
    }

    return $view;
}
```

My only gripe with this is that I have to manually set the template for the child view before I forward dispatch it, as it gets populated onDispatch with a default path if none was specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function registerAction () {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // Possible $form = new RegisterForm(); with validation and error population etc

    // If we're not requesting via AJAX, forward dispatch to index
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->forward()->dispatch('index', array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'overlay' => 1
        ));
    }

    $view = new ViewModel();
    $view->setTerminal(true);
    return $view;

}
```

Comment: Please, format your code properly (i.e. the `public function ...` clause and ehte last `}` should be included in the code block) and provide a brief introduction about it.